# Objective-C UISearchBar may not respond to setContentInset

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, compiler-warnings

Will the app containing this warning pass App Store review?

With the code, it gets actually rendered in iPhone simulator, but how should I remove the above-mentioned warning in Xcode?

EDIT 20 September 2011:

I will post the code that removes this warning someday.

EDIT 9 October 2011:

Here is my solution, as I could not find any other better and easier solution:

```
    UIView *extrablue = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250,0,80,40)];
    extrablue.backgroundColor = RGBCOLOR (95,95,95);
    [self.view addSubview:extrablue];
    mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 40)];
    //[mySearchBar setContentInset: UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,0,5,75)];
    mySearchBar.placeholder = @"Search a term here ... ";
    mySearchBar.backgroundColor = RGBCOLOR (95,95,95);
    mySearchBar.delegate = self;
    //[mySearchBar sizeToFit];
    mySearchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [mySearchBar setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [self.view addSubview: mySearchBar];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UISearchBar` does not contain the property `contentInset` - this is a property of `UIScrollView`. If your code is asking a `UISearchBar` to change its `contentInset` then this is a coding error, and should be removed.

If you need further help removing this, then some additional code would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that **UISearchBar** responds to the **setContentInset:** method (tested on iOS 5.0.1).

This result in a sofisticated approach involving **NSInvocation:**

```
    if([aSearchBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentInset:)]) {
        SEL aSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"setContentInset:");
        NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[aSearchBar methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector]];
        [inv setSelector:aSelector];
        [inv setTarget:aSearchBar];
        UIEdgeInsets anInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 5, 35);
        [inv setArgument:&anInsets atIndex:2]; //arguments 0 and 1 are self and _cmd respectively, automatically set by NSInvocation
        [inv invoke];
    }
```

The above code resizes the contentInset of the UISearchBar (effectively UITextField) using the CGRect indicated in the anInsets parameter.

the parent if-statement (respondsToSelector:) save yourself from changes of this behaviour in new versions of iOS.